# VpnOneClick problem with ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, vpn, responsiveness

after installing  VpnOneClick it doesn't respond when i want to run it:

[image: image description]

Comment: after entering password that i'm sure it's right but vpn respond like that picture and after two seconds nothing happens

Comment: VpnOneClick used to work perfectly for me until today..... Now I am in the same situation described by Sumeet Deshmukh HELP! The error in a terminal is:

* Error in `/usr/bin/vpn1click': double free or corruption (top): 0x09c10de0 *
HELP, please!

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 3 years.